# How to find the html tag of any text in which the text is contained

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsoup

Let suppose I have this html body

```html
<div style="height: 100%">
  <div class="vtex-rich-text-0-x-container">
    <div class="vtex-rich-text-0-x-wrapper">
      <p class="lh-copy vtex-rich-text-0-x-paragraph">
        <span class="b vtex-rich-text-0-x-strong">
Payless Shoesource Customer Care
</span>
        <br> 4910 Corporate Centre Dr, Suite 210<br> Lawrence, KS 66047<br> Customer.service@payless.com
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And someone has given me a text from the above html for eg: Lawrence I want to find the nearest html tag in which this Lawrence is present,which is `<p>` tag in our case and the content of that p tag. which is `<span class="b vtex-rich-text-0-x-strong">Payless Shoesource Customer Care</span><br> 4910 Corporate Centre Dr,  Suite 210<br> Lawrence, KS 66047<br> Customer.service@payless.com`

Comment: The content of the tag does not include the end tag `</p>`. Have you done any research into the subject, and made any attempts based on that research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find parent element of string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597213/find-parent-element-of-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Seems like duplicate to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50597853/5605822

Comment: *"someone has given me a text"*  How was it given? What is the input you get?

Comment: I am working with java so cannot use jquery in it. I am crawling the website and getting the html body out of it and then looking for some countries and state using NER and where I got the match I will try to look for parent tag of that text. So is there any way to do this without using jquery.

Comment: This question is incorrectly closed because the answer doesn't solve this problem and has nothing to do with Jsoup used here, which is a Java library, not JavaScript! Correct answer is: `doc.selectFirst(":containsOwn(Lawrence)")`